# I would like to know how to use command prompt in C language

Tags: c, command-prompt

I would like to know how to use command prompt in C language.

How do I get CMD to input commands in c language?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main() {

system("./aaa/bbb.exe -p ccccc ");  
system("pause");

}
```

I need to open command Prompt and entered 'bbb.exe -p ccccc' everytime.

So I want to make a program that executes the above command with a click.

this is error what i got

**'.' is not an internal or external command, a program that can run, or a batch file.**

Comment: I've never used windows CMD, but have you tried replacing ./ with .\\?

Comment: yep, but I got the same error.

Comment: If you open a command prompt and type `./aaa/bbb.exe -p ccccc ` does it work? You may need to `cd somewhere` first.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a few solutions i found on another forum.
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/753188/How-to-run-command-prompt-commands-from-a-c-progra

Comment: Answer posts should include the information that answers the question in the post. Links to external information may supplement an answer but do not serve Stack Overflow’s purpose to create a durable repository of questions and answers.

Comment: Just posting external links are not answers. These can be posted in comments as well.

Comment: Sry i didnt have enough reputation to post comments yet. 
Okay thanks @Eroc Postpischil didn't know that.